# Gradle: Proper way to add KAPT-generated Kotlin sources to sources JAR

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, kapt

I use KAPT to generate some code for my project and I want to include this generated code to sources.jar artifact.

Usual tip for that is to add generated folder to main source set, however this does not work: KAPT uses sources to do the generation and that would create a circular dependency.

I've managed to create this piece of build script:

```kotlin
kapt {
    annotationProcessor("com.example.MyGenerator")
}

sourceSets {
    create("generated") {
        kotlin {
           srcDir("${buildDir}/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main")
        }
    }
}

tasks.named<Jar>("sourcesJar").configure {
    dependsOn("jar") // A bit of overkill, but will do for the sake of example
    archiveClassifier = "sources"
    // main source set is already there
    from(sourceSets.named("generated").get().allSource)
}
```

This even works as expected: all the sources are in the JAR, however when I load the project into IntelliJ IDEA it shows the following warning:

```
Duplicate content roots detected
Path [C:/Users/gagar/IdeaProjects/example/example-module/build/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main] of module [example.example-module.generated] was removed from modules [example.example-module.main]
```

This leads me to a thought that generated sources are already on `main` sourceSet. However, when I try to generate `sourcesJar` from `main` source set, there are no generated sources. Debugging the build with `println` does not give me anything: for the main source set there is no generated folder and there are no other source sets besides `test`.

I wonder, is there a better way to fetch this generated source set from a build script?

Comment: You say just adding the output directory to the source set would create a circular dependency, but is this correct? Have you tried it? kapt just does one round of processing on the source that is there, and the result is added to the source set. Then the compilation can run, including the new source; plus that new source can be picked up in a sources JAR. There is no re-processing of the new source (you need KSP for that).

Comment: Uh, yes, seems like I misread an error message from gradle, it was just telling me that I have to add `kaptKotlin` dependency to `sourcesJar` task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, adding generated directory to the main source set is the right way after all. Also you need to declare `kaptKotlin` dependency to `sourcesJar` task:

```kotlin
kapt {
    annotationProcessor("com.example.MyGenerator")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin.srcDir("${layout.buildDirectory.get()}/generated/source/kaptKotlin/main")
    }
}

tasks.named<Jar>("sourcesJar").configure {
    dependsOn("kaptKotlin")
}
```